# Back-transforming Log data from a paired t.test (R)

Tags: r, t-test, lognormal-distribution, back-transformation

I am working with this data set:

```
structure(list(N2000 = c(4451493L, 627601L, 5165274L, 2678030L, 
34000446L, 4323410L, 3410079L, 786234L, 571066L, 16054328L, 8229823L, 
1212281L, 1299258L, 12435970L, 6089950L, 2927509L, 2691750L, 
4047424L, 4469970L, 1276961L, 5310908L, 6357072L, 9952006L, 4931093L, 
2849100L, 5603553L, 903157L, 1712577L, 2018723L, 1239881L, 8429007L, 
1821282L, 18989332L, 8077367L, 640919L, 11359955L, 3453250L, 
3429293L, 12282591L, 1050236L, 4023438L, 755509L, 5702027L, 20946503L, 
2241555L, 609709L, 7104016L, 5908372L, 1807099L, 5372243L, 494001L
), N2010 = c(4784762L, 714046L, 6410810L, 2922750L, 37334410L, 
5048472L, 3576616L, 899824L, 604989L, 18845967L, 9714748L, 1364274L, 
1570784L, 12840459L, 6489856L, 3050321L, 2858837L, 4346655L, 
4544125L, 1327585L, 5787998L, 6563259L, 9877670L, 5310737L, 2969137L, 
5996092L, 990735L, 1829696L, 2703758L, 1316843L, 8803388L, 2064767L, 
19399242L, 9559048L, 674363L, 11538290L, 3759482L, 3838212L, 
12711308L, 1052769L, 4635835L, 816223L, 6356673L, 25242683L, 
2775093L, 625916L, 8025105L, 6743636L, 1854019L, 5689591L, 564367L
), state = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 
24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 
50L, 51L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", 
"California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", "DC", "Delaware", "Florida", 
"Georgia", "Hawaii", "Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", 
"Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", 
"Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", 
"Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", 
"New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", 
"Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", 
"Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", 
"West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"), class = "factor")), .Names =    c("N2000", 
"N2010", "state"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -51L
))
```

'N2000' is a column with the population of each state (plus DC) in the year 2000. 'N2010' is the pop. for 2010. I am trying to compare the two columns to see if average populations per state differed significantly between the two years. In this case I am running a paired.t-test. Both N2000 and N2010 were not normally distributed so I log-transformed them for my t.test which was entered like this:

```
t.test(log(N2000), log(N2010), paired = T)
```

This t.test gave me an output with the mean of differences at around '0.090976' .

When I back transform this value using the exp() function I end up getting a value of 1.1.  This does not make sense and I don't understand why the back transformation is not working correctly. Any help to possible reasons why back-transforming log data using the exp() would be appreciated.

Comment: I find it hard to see this comparison as appropriate for a significance test if only because of queasiness about their interpretation as samples (from what precisely?). Also, no one is well served by testing differences known without doubt to exist! That said, the appropriate descriptive difference here is possibly between the geometric means, i.e. the difference between exp(mean(log(value))) for each group, not exp(difference between two mean(log(value))).

Comment: Does your confusion stem from the fact that the difference in means of the untransformed values (which I calculated as 533364.6) is not the same as the back-transformed mean of the difference in the means of the transformed values (which I calculated as 1.0952432)? If so, they should not be.

Comment: @ElmerVillanueva yes that's exactly the source of my confusion. I've been recently told that the 1.09 means that the average population from 2010 is actually 1.09 times larger than that of the average population from 2000.